# Significance of Grid in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm not able to understand the use case of `<Grid>`.

If I use `<Row>` without using `<Grid>`, it still renders the elements according to 12 column standard.

Then when should using `<Grid>` be appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

`<Grid>` is functioning in the same way as standard bootstrap `<div class="container">`. So if you have already applied it to your web page (for example as a container of the whole page), you don't need to nest every row element again into it. But remember that Rows must be placed within `<Grid>` (it is not mandatory for them (Rows) to be immediate child of `<Grid>` though)

Comment: So, I guess, to implement the 12 column system, `<Grid>` isn't necessary. Correct?

Comment: If you already wrapped any of your upper-level components into it then no. So the key is to have at least one `<Grid>` element in your web page where your `<Row>`-s will be wrapped. For example, if you already wrapped your high level `<App>` component into it then you don't need to use it elsewhere.